# DIscord Slash Commands Interaction Failed on discord py

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
async def _ping(ctx):  # Defines a new "context" (ctx) command called "ping."
    async def command_hi(ctx):
        await ctx.defer()
        await ctx.send("Pong!")
        pass
```

I was making slash commands and first time it worked but secondtime, it does not work.
I tried await ctx.defer() but it's not working either

Comment: can you show us more information, and more code please!

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Justnoob I recommend you to use Pycord, It has inbuilt Buttons, Slash, Dropdowns and much more but for now the discord api with application commands is a bit complicated we usually use `ctx.send` but in app commands it is `ctx.respond` so here is the code:-

```
async def ping(ctx): #Don't use _ping too.
await ctx.respond("Pong!")
```

And I still don't understand why you created two async def in one command. There should be only one and you already specified it.

Comment: btw i removed await ctx.defer() and pass and it worked.thanks for the respond btw

Comment: no need to thank.